# What does the following expression do <<EOF>tmp

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

A shell script with a database connection using sqlplus contains this line:

```
sqlplus username/password@DBNAME<<EOF>tmp.
(here there is a select sql query)
```

I know `<<EOF` indicates the start of the command. I have the below doubts in the `>tmp` part.

1)Does it indicate storing into a file?

2) If yes will it put the results of the SQL query alone into the tmp file or the query and the results both.

Could you please clear me on this one?

Comment: Wouldn't it be quicker to try it and see?

Answer (score 3):

`<<EOF` is known as "[heredocs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)". It means that from the next line in the script, up to a line that says "EOF", will be read in by the shell, and offered to the command on standard input.

In your case, the `sqlplus` command is being fed the SQL query as if it came from standard input. Then, the output of `sqlplus` is being saved to the file called `tmp`.

The input and output are separate. However, `sqlplus` as a command has a habit of repeating its input to the output, unless instructed otherwise with `SET ECHO OFF`.